# what the best way to write this without repeating myself

Tags: php, logic

A php file is going to receive a variable between 1 and 30 from a form using

```
 $style = $_GET['style'];
```

i want to then pass $style to help me choose the css stlye the user has selected so for example if the choice is style 3 then css stlye three will be passed to an image like this

```
<img style="<?php $choice3?>";  src="xxx.png" />
```

so what i have so far is this

```
<?php
 $style = $_GET['style'];

function choice1()
{
$choice1 = "display: block;padding:5px; etc, etc etc";
      return $choice1;      }   
function choice2()
{
$choice2 = "display: block;padding:10px; etc, etc etc";
    return $choice2;        }   
function choice3()
{
$choice3 = "display: block;padding:20px; etc, etc etc";
    return $choice3;        }   

if ($style == 1){
?>
<img style="<?php $choice1?>";  src="xxx.png" />
<?php 
}
if ($style == 2){
?>
<img style="<?php $choice2?>";  src="xxx.png" />
<?php 
}
.......and so on till 30        
?>
```

I am pretty sure there is an easier smarter way to convey my logic.

Comment: What are the other values you are setting? Perhaps we are able to see a pattern. Padding is always * 2.

Comment: is src always xxxpng? Can you associate xxx with $style? (good intelligent question btw)

Comment: your calls to style would need to call the function instead of $choice2, choice2()

Comment: @TobiasKun the values differ completely, because some will give rounded borders small borders etc

Comment: @Cups not really, the names will be diffferent for every image though the ext will be either png or jpg

Comment: @user1951739: Ok, well then you should go with DarkFalcon's answer :)

Comment: Can you control the img names SO they match the style number then? Does that come under your control?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about an array? Don't forget to check that `$style` is in the proper range before using the code below.

```
<?php
$style = $_GET['style'];
$styles = array(
  1=>"display: block;padding:5px; etc, etc etc",
  2=>"display: block;padding:15px; etc, etc etc",
  3=>"display: block;padding:35px; etc, etc etc",
  4=>"display: block;padding:55px; etc, etc etc",
  // etc.
);
?>

<img style="<?php echo $styles[$style]; ?>";  src="xxx.png" />
```

Comment: +1 I would also suggested that you replace the inline styles with CSS class names

Comment: +1. Good way to use an array. Switch-clause would be confusing. But perhaps if the asker shows more of his code we can simplify it more than this.

Comment: @TobiasKun: Indeed, but his existing code does not even make sense, so I worked with what I had. :)

Comment: @Dark Falcon, i like, i like very much, so i will make sure on form submit that it checks this right(range), let me try your solution

Comment: @DarkFalcon: This was not an allegation :) I just thought about it, but since he clarified that the css properties vary strongly this is the best answer!

Comment: @DarkFalcon since i am receiving $styles from a form, how would the first part of your code look like. Just before you say $styles = array(....... , i am not sure how to make it compare the values after the $_GET .

Comment: `styles` does not come from a form. Only `style` comes from the form, just like you already get it from the form.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Only the Padding Value is changing than ,why you are not trying this :

```
 $style = $_GET['style'];

    <img style="display: block;padding:<?php echo $choice3; ?>px;"  src="xxx.png" />
```

Comment: Since there is no "etc" property in css i think that there are some other values he sets.

Comment: @TobiasKun ,yes in that case dark 's Answers Is best.

Answer (score 0):

I would change your function to handle all the borders instead of having multiple so something like:

```
  function border($style){
  switch ($style) {
    case 0:
        $border = "display: block;padding:5px; etc, etc etc";
        break;
    case 1:
        $border = "display: block;padding:5px; etc, etc etc";
        break;
    case 2:
        $border = "display: block;padding:5px; etc, etc etc";
        break;
    default:
        $border = "display: block;padding:5px; etc, etc etc";
   }
   return $border;
  }
```

Comment: Since there are more than 30 possible values an array would be the better way like @DarkFalcon suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code looks ok - but needs a print/echo before the var.

```
<img style="<?php print $choice2; ?>" src="..." />
```

Also, you could try using a switch statement.

----- edit -----

Instead of applying the style, I would pass a class name.

```
<img class="<?php print $choice2; ?>" src="..." />
```

Then you can always specify the CSS in your stylesheet instead of inline.

Answer (score 0):

I might set it up like this:

```
$myStyles = new Array();
$myStyles[0] = "display: block;padding:5px; etc, etc etc";
$myStyles[1] = "display: block;padding:10px; etc, etc etc";
```

etc...

```
function getStyles($style){
      return $myStyles[$style - 1];
}

<img style="<?php echo getStyles($_GET['style']; ?>";  src="xxx.png" />
```

Not tested...